# DataTable with existing Schema not Importing DataRow of same Schema

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, datarow

Greets! I am having problems importing a row I created into a DataTable that resides in a DataSet.  I pre-populate the "newDataSet" from a SQL Database that is empty but it does contain Tables with a Schema already set up.  I have verified that the DataTables in "newDataSet" are getting the Schema imported to them.

Everything looks right as there is no error logs, but no datarow is ever added. Both my Console.WriteLine report back the same Count.

Thank you for taking the time to review this.  I appreciate you.

Initial Setup:

```
var DataSet newDataSet = new DataSet("foo"); // A SQL Adapater was used to fill this from a pre existing Database.
var checkDataSet = new DataSet();
var checkDataTable = new DataTable();
```

Cloning the DataSet and DataTable.

```
checkDataSet = newDataSet.Clone();
checkDataTable = checkDataSet.Tables["moreFoo"].Clone();
```

Creating the DataRow:

```
var newDataRow = checkDataTable.NewRow();
```

Filling the Columns in the DataRow:

```
newDataRow[0] = obj1;
newDataRow[1] = obj2;
newDataRow[2] = obj3;
```

Importing the DataRow to the "newDataSet" DataTable:

```
Console.WriteLine(newDataSet.Tables["moreFoo"].Rows.Count.ToString()); 
newDataSet.Tables["moreFoo"].ImportRow(newDataRow);
Console.WritelLine(newDataSet.Tables["moreFoo"].Rows.Count.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
newDataSet.Tables["moreFoo"].ImportRow(newDataRow);
```

should be:

```
newDataSet.Tables["moreFoo"].Rows.Add(newDataRow.ItemArray);
```